# MDI child with FormBorderStyle = None not maximizing correctly

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

I am writing an application using Windows Forms. I need to use MDI child with FormBorderStyle set to None. Problem is, when I maximize, child doesn't show up correctly. Code to show Form2 is:

```
  this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  Form2 frm = new Form2();
  frm.MdiParent = this;
  frm.Size = this.ClientSize;
  frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
  frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  frm.Show();
```

Here's how Form2 looks in designer:

[image]

And here's application:

[image]

How to fix this to show Form2 correctly?

Comment: Easily solvable by using `UserControl` instead of MDI parenting. I never did find any use for MDI forms. A window within a window makes no sense to me

Comment: I suggest to give `frm.Show(this)` a try. And maybe maximizing the parent after the child has been added makes a difference.

Comment: @René Vogt Thank you for input. However, frm.Show(this) throws an exception: Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling Show. So I cannot use it with MDI. Maximizing afterwards gives the same result as described in the post.

Comment: MDI doesn't properly support borderless forms.  It would be better to go non-MDI and put your borderless child forms (or UserControls) inside a panel instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. It appears to do what you are looking for.

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        //frm.Size = this.ClientSize;
        frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        //frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        frm.Show();
```

The only change was added frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; and commented out setting the size and window state of Form2.

When I run the program this is the effect.

[image]

I do agree this seems to be the wrong way to get this effect and a user control would be better most likely.